# SELECT all records but the highest

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, mediawiki

I have three tables.

```
 Page                           Revision                                   Text                       
 +-----------+-------------+    +-----------+-------------+----------+     +-------------+---------+
 | page_id   | rev_id      |    | rev _id   | rev_text_id | page_id  |     | rev_text_id | text    |
 +-----------+-------------+    +-----------+-------------+----------+     +-------------+---------+
 |      1    |     2       |    |      1    |     1       |    1     |     |      1      |     A   |
 +--------------------------    +------------------------------------+     +-----------------------+
 |      2    |     5       |    |      2    |     2       |    1     |     |      2      |     B   |
 +-------------------------+    +------------------------------------+     +-----------------------+
                                |      3    |     3       |    2     |     |      3      |     C   |
                                +------------------------------------+     +-----------------------+
                                |      4    |     4       |    2     |     |      4      |     D   |
                                +------------------------------------+     +-----------------------+
                                |      5    |     4       |    2     |               
                                +------------------------------------+
```

My desired output is:

```
 +--------+-------------+
 | rev_id | rev_text_id |
 +--------+-------------+
 |   1    |      1      |
 +----------------------+
 |   3    |      3      |
 +----------------------+
 |   4    |             |
 +----------------------+
```

My goal is to find rev_id's and rev_text_id's that can be deleted from each table in a single query. As the revision table can hold equal rev_text_id's for multiple revisions, I need to exclude the rev_text_id that is highest for each page (in the example 4 for page 2).

I began dabbling along the lines of:

```
 SELECT
 r.rev_id,r.rev_text_id
 FROM revision r, page p, text t
 WHERE p.page_id = r.page_id
 AND t.rev_text_id = r.rev_text_id 
 AND p.rev_id != r.rev_id
 AND r.rev_text_id not in (
      SELECT max(r.rev_text_id)
      FROM revision AS r, page AS p
      WHERE r.rev_id = p.rev_id
 );
```

But that skips the record for rev_id 4 in my desired output and doesn't include the "null cases" ..

Comment: Please show you current SQL query

Comment: Consider providing an sqlfiddle of same and, for the sake of everyone's sanity, consider renaming the columns to `rev_id`, `page_id`, and `rev_text_id` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.`rev_id`, r.`rev_text_id`
FROM `Revision` AS r
WHERE r.`rev_text_id` NOT IN (SELECT r.`rev_text_id`
                              FROM `Revision` AS r, `Page` AS p
                              WHERE r.`rev_id` = p.`page_latest`;)
ORDER BY r.`rev_id`;
```

This basically grabs the rev_id's that equal the page_latest, finds the rev_text_id's associated with those rev_id's, and uses those rev_text_id's as the filter.

Comment: That query does not return rev_id 4, correctly since you filter away those revisions that has the same rev_id as page_latest. The output I want includes rev_id 4 without the rev_text_id attached in the output. I guess this has to be obtained using a join?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do this in pure SQL then.  I don't know of a way to separate the cells in a row like that.  You might have to handle that in PHP after the query.